# pyinstaller working but .exe application not staring up

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I tried to convert my python gui application (.py ) to an executable file(.exe) using the pyinstaller module. I ran the following command in the terminal -

pyinstaller.exe --onefile -w sourcecode.py

The process was completed successfully and I got the .exe file(sourcecode.exe) along with the extra folders like pycache and sourcecode. But when I tried to run the .exe file/application by double clicking on it the app didn't start up and gave an error. Please help.[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this `--hidden-import` to `pyinstaller.exe --onefile -w sourcecode.py` in case of hidden modules.

You can also try adding `--debug` to see what the error actually is.

Comment: Anyways I used cx_Freeze instead of pyinstaller and it worked perfectly. The process was just a bit lengthy though.